# Non linear ODE $(y')^2+yy'-x^2-xy=0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, proof-verification

This question in

Non linear ODE - solve by factorization method :

$(y')^2+yy'-x^2-xy=0$

$(y'-x)(y'+(x+y))=0$

- Either

$y'-x=0$

So ${dy\over dx}-x=0$

$y-{1\over 2} x^2 -c=0$

- or

$y'+(x+y)=0$

$y'=-(x+y)$

Let $z=x+y$ then ${dz\over dx}=1+{dy\over dx}$

So

${dz\over dx}-1=-z$

$\int {1\over {1-z}} dz+\ln c =\int dx$

And I get:

$ln(1-z)-\ln c=-x$

$1-z=ce^{-x}$

$1-x-y=ce^{-x}$

$y+x+ce^{-x}-1=0$

So the general solution is

$(y-{1\over 2} x^2 -c)(y+x+ce^{-x}-1)=0$

true ?

Thanks.

Factorization method:

[Non linear ODE $(y')^2+yy'-x^2-xy=0$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1993886/non-linear-ode-y2yy-x2-xy-0#comment4093886_1993886)

Comment: For your second note, I edited the sign in $\ln (1-z)-\ln c=-x$ true know ?

Comment: and i wrote the general solution like that because in factorization method of ODE we write it like that $(p-f_1)(p-f_2)...(p-f_n)=0$ such $f_1, f_2, ... , f_n$ functions in $x,y$ in $n$ differential equations from the first order and first degree , then $p=f_1 \ p=f_2 \ ... \ p=f_n$ and we get $\Phi_1(x,y,c)=0$ , $\Phi_2(x,y,c)=0$ ... $\Phi_n(x,y)=0$ and the general solution is : $\Phi_1(x,y,c).\Phi_1(x,y,c)...\Phi_n(x,y,c)=0$ ,

Comment: @Moo in your last comment, are you suru $y(x) = 1 - x + c e^{-x}$ ? I get $y(x) = 1 - x - c e^{-x}$

Comment: @ Dima : Your result is OK, except the notation of the constants because the two constants are not necessarily the same : $$(y-{1\over 2} x^2 -c_1)(y+x+c_2e^{-x}-1)=0$$